# Ionic 2 saving to not being able to save to storage

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I have a few lists I want to save to the local storage.

I've been using this line :

```
this.http.get("http://beta.webite.com/api/option/jobtype").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
                    (res) => {
                        localStorage.setItem  ("jobType", JSON.stringify(res)); 
                    }, (err) => {
                        reject(err)
                    });
```

the result that I am trying to save to the local storage looks like this :

> {"0":"Others","1":"Internship","2":"Fresh/Entry Level","3":"Junior
>   Executive","4":"Senior Executive","5":"Manager","6":"Senior
>   Manager","7":"Director/C-Level","":"Select position level"}

but the issue is not all the lists are saved to the local storage. Out of 5 lists, 2 or 3 would save to the local storage. Why does this happen ?

I have also tried following

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage/

but it only works on the device, and i need to first continue building the application through the webview first. Any advice on how I can save all the needed data to the local storage ?

Comment: could you please add the code where you save the data in the storage?

Comment: that is the code where I save the data to the storage, I am using the build in localStorage.setItem

Comment: are you using that line of code inside of a loop?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add to the post how that lists look like? I'm just trying to think what could be going wrong in your code, seems ok to be honest...